# Unlimited Offline Storage

Tags: google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Our project needs to store like 200Gb of images for offline usage!

I am making a PWA using Workbox and then setting its URL as the `homepage` parameter for “[Chrome App Builder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-app-builder/ighkikkfkalojiibipjigpccggljgdff?hl=en)”

Then this Chrome App will be set to work in [Kiosk mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3316168?hl=en).

The project requirements are that the whole kiosk with all its content should be able to work offline, which means it needs to store like 200Gb of images mostly.

From my research, it seems that it is not possible for a PWA to store more than 6% of available disk space (on chrome).
I am sure that is not enough for our use-case.

Although there is permission named `unlimitedStorage` for [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions), I am not sure if that's the way to go! Apparently, I am confusing concepts!

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage for guidance around requesting persistent storage. This does not exempt you from the overall quota limitations, but it makes your origin's storage less likely to be auto-cleared when a device experiences low-space.

I'd strongly suggest looking into whether an alternative image format will end up allowing you to store the same number of images in less overall space. If you know that you're using are going to be on Chrome, for instance, then [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) will definitely be supported. Converting your images to WebP (or otherwise optimizing them) sounds like it would be an important step to take.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff. I really appreciate your response. Definitely will look into persistent storage.

Answer (score 2):

From our experience, the `unlimitedStorage` doesn't apply to a webview (which is what Chrome App Builder uses).

We've had the same issue and we bypassed it by downloading and storing assets in the Chrome app and establishing a communication between the Chrome app and the Webview.
We used `myWebView.contentWindow.postMessage` which is identical to the HTML5 postMessage API to send blob versions of the files when needed and receive the URLs to download :

```
Webview --URL to download--> Chrome App

Webview <--BLOB file-- Chrome App
```

Careful: You'll be limited by the amount of RAM your device has (because you'll need to load the file in memory to send it between the ChromeApp and Webview)

Comment: Nice! I ended up using `chrome.socket` api to add a webserver inside the app and intercept `webview.request` then redirect to local server. Then the local server could load the image from filesystem!!

Comment: Could you please also take a look at this questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434246/webview-request-access-to-requests-initiated-by-the-service-worker

Comment: That's a really interesting idea, I'll look into it! What are you building? I'll also have a look at your other question